# ngResource query with composite key parameter

Tags: angularjs, ngroute

I have a resource, `Answer`, which has a composite key made of `QuestionnaireId` and `QuestionId`. The ngResource code is as follows:

```
function answerResource($resource) {
    return $resource("/api/answers/:questionnaireId/:questionId",
        {
            questionnaireId: "@questionnaireId",
            questionId: "@questionId"
        }
    );
}
```

I want to query this resource with the the questionnaire Id and get back all the answers. If I use:

```
answerResource.query(
    {
        questionnaireId: questionnaireId
    }
);
```

Then the requested url is:

```
/api/answers/123
```

When I want it to be:

```
/api/answers?questionnaireId=123
```

Otherwise I have two routes that I need to handle for the query search - one with the Id in the querystring, the other with the Id as part of the url path. (I also have queries with search text where the questionnaire Id might not be present, that would use urls like `/api/answers?q=sometext`).

Surely any `.query` parameters should be passed as querystrings, not as part of the route. How do I get the desired behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best option I can come up with, is to create a new `search` method on the resource, which doesn't have the parameters in the url:

```
// normal resource definition here...
,{
    search: {
        method: "GET",
        url: "/api/answers",
        isArray: true
    }
}
```

Calling that with the composite key values will append them as querystring parameters and not as part of the url, e.g. `/api/answers?questionnaireId=123`

Comment: You can also overwrite the `query` method if you are not using it for something else.

Answer (score 0):

Faced a similar issue, but I'm messing with composite key (item, sequence).
1- html.erb: Borrowed option 2 from https://spin.atomicobject.com/2013/11/22/pass-rails-data-angularjs/
That way I could grab inside the .js script the item from the .erb form I already have (I'm doing some kind of "manage details -- crud" on request with angularjs)
2- in the controller .js file I grab the value from the custom data in the html element using document.getElementById and getAttribute, concatenating that to the request: '/items?personId='+div.getAttribute("data-personId")+'&format=json'
3- in the items_controller index action, by default rails g expects no argument and grabs all items, then I had to ask

if params[:personId].present?
      @items = Item.where(personId: params[:personId]) 
   else 
      grab-all-items
   end

This works, but I'm not sure if it's the best approach because I'm a real newbie for angularjs.
Just messing with this issue, cannot figure yet how to remove a record.

Comment: BTW, the CRUD is already working but I guess it's a bit piggy the way I had to workaround with the items_controller (Let's acknowledge that it's a issue with the composite key, not with Rails nor Angularjs).

Answer (score 0):

$resource crete path instead of querystring because you define placeholders :

```
return $resource("/api/answers/:questionnaireId/:questionId"..
```

If you delete them from resource-level and then call [$resource.query({param: value})](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) you can make querystring, also you can specify more actions for single $resource to perform different request overriding action url property.

I created a simple (and very fast) example might help you understand:

working example :https://jsfiddle.net/Nedev_so/b71feyc6/19/

EDIT :
after your comment i understand what you need, so

resource factory :

```
 //only for example purpose
 var answersBaseUrl = "https://example.com/api/answers";

 var answerTemplateUri = commentsBaseUrl + '/:questionnaireId/:questionId'

 var params = {questionnaireId: '@_questionnaireId',questionId: '@_questionId'};

 var  res = $resource(answerTemplateUri, params,{
   one :{
       method: "GET",
     },
   all: {
        method: "GET",
        url: answersBaseUrl,
        isArray: true
    }


  });

      return res;
});
```

and then in your controller :

```
//get answers by questionnaire
//GET /answers?questionnaireId=123
$scope.answersByQuestionnaire = answers.all({questionnaireId: 123});

 //get answers by question
 //GET /answers?questionId=123
 $scope.answersByQuestion = answers.all({questionId:123}); 

 //get single answer by questionnaire and question
 //GET /answers/123/123
 $scope.answer = answers.one({questionnaireId: 123,questionId:123 });
```

(check network logs and you can see expected behaviour)

Comment: But then how do I use the resource to `GET` a single entry, using the key fields? The REST service has the format `answers/questionnaireid/questionid` but without the placeholders, I expect you'll end up with parameters in the querystring, solving one problem but creating another.

Comment: OK, so uri for single entry : answers/questionnaireid/questionid AND query string for search : answers?param=value. Check my last edit. same function in dedicated factory that allow you to query one or all entities.

Comment: Yep, I think that's effectively the same as the answer I provided.